# Access is denied error in Windows Store App using Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to launch a save dialog in my windows RT app when someone tries to close a file which has not been saved. However, I keep getting a `0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied` error

This is the code I'm using the launch the message dialog. When "Don't Save" is chosen (and `BlankFile()` is run) everything runs ok. However when you choose "Save File" it throws the access denied error when it tries to run `.pickSaveFileAsync()`

```
function createNewFile() 
{
    if (editedSinceSave)
    {
        // Create the message dialog and set its content 
        var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Save this file?", 
            "Save Changes");

        // Add commands 
        msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Don't Save", 
            function (command) {
                BlankFile();
            }));

        msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Save File", 
            function (command) {
                //saveFile(true, true);
                testPop("test");
            }));

        // Set the command that will be invoked by default 
        msg.defaultCommandIndex = 2;

        // Show the message dialog 
        msg.showAsync();
    }
}

function testPop(text) {
    var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(text, "");
    msg.showAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core problem is you are tying to show a message dialog ontop of another. I discuss the details, and the solution here:
[What is the alternative to `alert` in metro apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652413/what-is-the-alternative-to-alert-in-metro-apps/13655351#13655351)

However, you flow naturally needs this is to happen -- I suggest looking at building a different type of flow rather than stacking dialogs.

Comment: Ah! I see what you're saying about the flow, but what's the alternative here? if someone tries to close a file without saving, the standard procedure is to prompt them to save and show a file picker dialog. I don't see a way around this flow

Comment: You can probably solve this by pushing the call to the picker through a WinJS.promise.timeout deferral?

Comment: seems like the done function of showAsync is a better fit. I think I'll just leave as is

Comment: Hi Dominic. Should have accepted this answer a long time ago, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

The way around this seems to be to set a command id and catch it in the `done()` function of `showAsync()`, like so

```
function createNewFile() 
{
    if (editedSinceSave)
    {
        // Add commands and set their CommandIds 
        msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Dont Save", null, 1));
        msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Save File", null, 2));

        // Set the command that will be invoked by default 
        msg.defaultCommandIndex = 1;

        // Show the message dialog 
        msg.showAsync().done(function (command) {
            if (command) {
                if (command.id == 1){
                    BlankFile();
                }
                else {
                    saveFile(true, true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This doesn't throw any errors. I don't know why doing it the other way throws errors as it doesn't seem to be any different!

Comment: Of course it is different. In your original code, you attempt to create a dialog on top of an existing one by adding a function to the Save command, This isn't allowed in WinJS application.
In your modified version. you are hooking into the "done" continuation method. So now, your "Save file" code will be executed *after* the popup is closed (by hitting the "Save File" button). 

BTW, logically, this is also the right way. Once user has clicked the Save button, you don't need the dialog anymore.