# Metro app - Pop up window JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a Metro app using JavaScript and I can't find a way to create a pop up window.

An example of what I'm trying to do is shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to do it using JavaScript (no jQuery)?

I'm trying to use `alert` but when I hit run in Visual Studio I get the error below:

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'alert' is undefined
```

[JSFIDDLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz5dA/)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <button id="about">About</button>
    </header>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function button(){
    var about = document.getElementById("about");
    about.addEventListener("click", buttonAboutHandler, false);  
}

function buttonAboutHandler(eventinfo) {
    alert("About");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652413/what-is-the-alternative-to-alert-in-metro-apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use messageDialogbox class

```
var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(string);
```

and then display it by using

```
.showAsync()
```

method.
use this code in your event handeler and whenever the event triggers popup will appear.

```
var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("About", "your text");
messageDialog.showAsync();
```

reference:[MessageDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208674)

Answer (score 2):

First. You need to register your event on window `onload` that solves your problem, to attach the event of click.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qz5dA/1/

Now to create a dialog without Jquery with pure javascript create div and define your css to create the efect

http://jsfiddle.net/Qz5dA/4/

Comment: It doesn't work in my case (Metro app). I think that `alert` is not supported by Metro apps because it is a browser function.

Comment: I think that maybe you need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652413/what-is-the-alternative-to-alert-in-metro-apps